# TypeError: google.visualization is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I've been trying to use the Google Charts API to my Dashboard and see these error on firebug.

TypeError: google.visualization is undefined

[image: TypeError: google.visualization is undefined]

Here is my JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Title', 'Values'],
            ['TBK', 8],
            ['Fluor Corp', 12],
            ['Fluor Group', 41],
            ['Bechtel', 39]
        ]);

        var options = {
            legend: 'none',
            pieSliceText: 'none',
            chartArea: {
                width: '90%',
                height: '90%',
            },
            colors:['#fa424a','#ac6bec','#fdad2a','#00a8ff','#46c35f','#e84f9a'],
            slices: {
                0: { color: '#fa424a' },
                1: { color: '#ac6bec' },
                2: { color: '#fdad2a' },
                3: { color: '#00a8ff' }
            },
            pieHole: 0.8,
            tooltip: { trigger: 'none' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

need to load the library before using the callback...

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages:['corechart']});  // <-- load
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

you can also add the callback to the load statement...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

or use the promise the load statement returns...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(drawChart);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit later but i have the same problem.
My problem was that the object google.visualization wasn`t ready when i call the function (i call in execution time, not with setOnLoadCallback).

So i call the function a bit later with an interval and its works for me:

```
function drawChart(){

    timeout1 = setInterval( 
            function () {
                data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('string', 'Colum1');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Colum2');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Colum3');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Colum4');

                chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('div_Chart'));
                .
                .
                .
                clearInterval(timeout1);
            }, 100);   
}
```

I hope its help u.